# shoutcast pls forbidden for iPhone programmatically?

Tags: iphone, nsurlconnection, shoutcast

I have been trying to access the pls file data from shoutcast for some testing but the response seems to be forbidden and I am getting 403 as response.
here is the code

```
NSURL *myurl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://yp.shoutcast.com/sbin/tunein-station.pls?id=9944"] ;

//Accept:*/*
NSMutableURLRequest *myrequest = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:myurl];
[myrequest setValue:@"*/*" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];

//NSURL *myurl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"];
NSURLConnection *theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:myrequest  delegate:self];
```

On the response, it was showing a 403 and no data is received. I tried to check the content-type and it was showing audio/x-scpls

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case of disallowing NSURLRequests, changing the submitted user agent should avoid the 403 response:

```
[myRequest setValue:userAgent forHTTPHeaderField:@"useragent"];
```

Comment: yes. the issue got solved when i changed the useragent

    [myrequest setValue:@"iPhoneRadio/2.0" forHTTPHeaderField:@"User-Agent"];
Thanks

Comment: Is it legal to use this without a developer key? It looks like shoutcast ask for an email regarding partnering and using their API?